# PHP mysql_* converting to mysqli fatal error

Tags: php, mysqli

I have my mysql_* converting to mysqli, but I encounter below issue.

php class (Functions.php):

```
class Functions{

    public static function filter($data){
        $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));

        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = $mysqli->real_escape_string($data);

            return $data;
        }

}
```

DB connection (dbconnect.php):

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'xxxxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxxxxx';
$dbname = 'xxxxxx';

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

I include above file in header.php like

```
include('inc/dbconnect.php');
include('inc/Functions.php');
```

I had my page call the class function like:

```
$params = Functions::filter($_GET['param']);
```

I got this error when I load the page:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\inc\functions.php on line XX

Isn't I already created an object for mysqli in dbconnect.php? why it show this error? it happen to all related mysqli in Functions.php.

Please advise, many thanks.

Comment: you're not supposed to do it that way with mysqli, but to use prepared statements/parameterized queries. otherwise you kinda miss the point

Comment: You've created mysqli object in the global scope, so you have to add `global $mysqli;` to your method or use `$GLOBALS['mysqli']` instead. But I suggest passing the object as an function argument

Comment: Can I have practice sample work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created mysqli object in the global scope, so you have to add `global $mysqli;` to your method or use `$GLOBALS['mysqli']` instead:

```
public static function filter($data) {
    global $mysqli;

    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = $mysqli->real_escape_string($data);

        return $data;
    }
}
```

But I suggest passing the object as an function argument:

```
public static function filter($data, $mysqli) {
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = $mysqli->real_escape_string($data);

        return $data;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
$params = Functions::filter($_GET['param'], $mysqli);
```

Comment: Thanks..it fix the error, does it means I have to use this way in all kind of class method or function?

Comment: @conmen, no it's **very** bad practice to use globals. Just follow the tips in my answer.

Comment: It's good practise to inject dependencies into class/method, and not rely on existance of some global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make `$mysqli` accessible from the global scope therefore you should declare `global $mysqli` inside the `Functions::filter` method.

The use of static classes and globals is highly discouraged when possible. You can edit your `Functions` class to be more OOP oriented by:

```
class Functions {

    private $mysqli;
```

declaring a private property to hold the `mysqli` object. Notice that we cannot allow `NULL` there. Therefore we need to declare a constructor to initialize our property:

```
    public function __construct(mysqli $mysqli_) {
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli_;
    }
```

which, with the type hinting, will avoid anything that is not an object of `mysqli` to be passed as parameter. Now we just need to make the `filter` method an instance method:

```
    public function filter($data){
        $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));

        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($data);

        return $data;
    }
```

}

Notice that `$mysqli` is now `$this->mysqli` because we are using the instance property of the class.

Comment: I try your tips but getting this error `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Functions::__construct() must be an instance of mysqli, none given...`

Comment: @conmen, yes, because you didn't passed a valid `mysqli` object to the constructor. Have you even tried with `$functions = new Functions($mysqli); $params = $functions->filter($_GET['param']);`?

Comment: now is another error, `Fatal error: Cannot access empty property`